# How to get SQL Server schema changes especially "column name" changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, ddl-trigger

I am using trigger to trace DDL changes but when I change column name from the SQL Server Management Studio the trigger is not working?

```
create TRIGGER trgLogDDLEvent ON DATABASE
  FOR DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS
FOR
AS
DECLARE @data XML
SET @data = EVENTDATA()
IF @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
<> 'CREATE_STATISTICS'
INSERT INTO db_trc_DDLChangeLog
(
EventType,
ObjectName,
ObjectType,
tsql,
RecDate,
HostName
)
VALUES (
@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]',
'nvarchar(100)'),
@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]',
'nvarchar(100)'),
@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)[1]',
'nvarchar(100)'),
@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]',
'nvarchar(max)'),
getdate(),
 HOST_NAME()
) ;
GO

--select * from db_trc_DDLChangeLog
--create table db_trc_DDLChangeLog
--(
--EventType varchar(max),
--ObjectName varchar(max),
--ObjectType varchar(max),
--tsql varchar(max),
--RecDate datetime,
--HostName varchar(max)
--)
```

Comment: If you are changing database structure from the Object Explorer and not a script, then stop that right now. No database change should ever be made without a script that is in source control.

Comment: I just want to trace this changes for security.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get events specifically for column changes. Instead you'll receive an `ALTER_TABLE` event to indicate the table has changed.

When you say SQL Server console do you mean Management Studio? If so, have a look at the SQL it is generating to alter your table. It might be creating a new table, copying the data to it, dropping the old table and renaming the new table so you will see a number of events like `CREATE_TABLE` and then `DROP_TABLE`.

Comment: Yes I mean Management studio. trigger is running for  all DLL events is't it?: FOR DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS. I also tried CREATE_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE, DROP_TABLE, events and is was not worked.

Comment: Is your trigger being called at all? Could there be some other problem preventing a row being inserted into db_trc_DDLChangeLog? Also, if the SQL generated by management studio is using sp_rename it won't cause a DDL event to be raised in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: no problem for db_trc_DDLChangeLog because when i drop table it writes to log ı think sp_rename not firing DDL event..

Comment: Yeah - sp_rename was fixed for SQL 2008 but in 2005 it won't raise an event.